# Copy all files from an HTTP folder location to a local folder

Tags: windows, http

I'm a student and need to pull down lots of stuff from my professor’s website, preferably retaining some of the folder structure.

I'm working on Windows boxes and have access to Windows XP, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008 R2.  Way back in the day (2-3 years ago) I tried some utilities that mirrored web pages and that sort of thing and for varying reasons they never worked right, or I could never get what I wanted from them.

So, for example, these folders:

```
http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder1/programmaticFolderABCXYZ

http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder1/programmaticFolder123456

http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder1/programmaticFolder4321

http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder1/programmaticFolder2345

http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder2/programmaticFolderABCXYZ2

http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder2/programmaticFolder1234563

http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder2/programmaticFolder43214

http://myUniversity.edu/professor/classLectures/folder2/programmaticFolder23455
```

In essence, a real pain to try to download manually for later use.

I've tried [this utility](http://www.httrack.com/) and  either it's overkill, or not-simple-enough-kill because I could never get it to just download files to my hard drive.

Ideally, I'd like to recursively scan the folder, recreate the folder structure in some specified folder, then copy the files from the remote server to their corresponding folder on my local machine.

Comment: Are the server folders browseable or linked from a page? Keep in mind that usually "http folders" are not browseable.

Comment: +1 4 not-simple-enough-kill , ha ha

Answer (score 9):

The simplest utility to download the files from web site recursively is WGET:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: Using wget would get you the a file named after the webpage (directory in our case), containing just the html.

Comment: Got that. wget -r. Cool..! :)

Comment: Tried this tool  and it's excellent. For the sake of others, you open C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ with the Command prompt, and wget -r url_to_download_files

Comment: Just found this Dec 2017 at https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualwget/ - and it works great.  TNX.

Comment: wget crashes on large files.

Answer (score 5):

Look at using [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/):

> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a
>   local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML,
>   images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack
>   arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a
>   page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the
>   site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can
>   also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted
>   downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help
>   system.

Comment: That's the utility that I said I tried and couldn't get to work. :-/  The description sounds great but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Of all solutions, this is the only one that worked for me (on Mac OSX).

Comment: It also worked for me like a charm (y).

Answer (score 5):

Firefox addon: [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)

Chrome extension: [GetThemAll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/getthemall-downloader/nbkekaeindpfpcoldfckljplboolgkfm?hl=en)